# ExtJS: build app testing with chart failed

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, bar-chart

I have a problem by building a testing app with charts. I've build with sencha cmd an app and developed my app. Now I tried to build a testing app with sencha cmd and now I get the error

`Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: series.bar`

the
Store:

```
Ext.define('test.store.statisticKey', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'test.model.statisticKey',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
id: 'storestatisticKey',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '../getStatisticKey.php',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

the code for my Chart:

```
Ext.define('test.view.Chart1', {
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
alias: 'widget.Chart1',
width: 350,
height: 300,
animate: true,
id: 'statisticKeyID',
store: 'statisticKey',
border: 0,
axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['count'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['key']
    }],
series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('key') + ': ' + storeItem.get('count') + ' Patienten');
            }
        },
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'count',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'key',
        yField: ['count']
    }]
    });
```

In my Dev-System all is fine but when I build a test system I get the error and no Chart is shown.

Thx for the Help

Comment: Show the code where you create `test.view.Chart1`

Answer (score 0):

See if you get "synchronous" warnings in console while developing and fix them if yes.

If still in trouble try

```
sencha ant clean
```

before building.